# Find arctan without calculator

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Does there exist any formula to calculate the value of $\arctan$ without a calculator? Suppose I'm writing an exam and I have to find the value of $\arctan(0.52)$, how can I go about it?
This can be an approximation formula like Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula $\displaystyle \sin x^{\circ} \approx \frac{4x(180-x)}{40500-x(180-x)}$.

Any alternative methods are also appreciated.

Comment: Check $\arctan(0.52^{\circ})$, it takes real numbers as input.

Comment: @user I'm sorry, I do not understand?

Comment: @Aditya The argument to $\arctan$ should not be an angle.

Comment: @L.F. my mistake, corrected.

Comment: https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Documents/EfficientApproximationArctgFunction.pdf

Comment: The arctan function does not take an angle as argument. It takes a number  without dimension and returns an angle.

Comment: @TravisWillse That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: In an exam where calculators are not allowed, does one ever have to compute arc tangents of arbitrary numbers? If you remember the "simple" values of the tangent such as $\tan(30^\circ),$ $\tan(45^\circ),$ and $\tan(60^\circ),$ those will cover most cases where the exact value of the angle matters. For $\arctan(0.52)$ I would expect to just be able to write the answer using that exact same expression.

Comment: **If** an exam ever asks you to compute $\arctan x$ for a given non-obvious $x$ (e.g. $x\ne 1$), it's very likely the exam would ask you to use an approximation method (of your choice, or not), and you are not supposed to learn approximate formulas for every function. For instance, use what you know about the power series of $\arctan x$ to find (and prove) an approximation up to $n$ digits. In more general cases, you would be given proper computational means (which could be a calculator, or a table of logarithms and trigonometric functions, or a slide rule, or whatever).

Comment: @TravisWillse. It is funny to see in the ling that $\frac{x}{1+\frac{9}{32}x^2}$ is a real good approximation. The corresponding norm would be $7.61\times 10^{-6}$. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Travis Willse answered, we just need to consider the case where $0\leq x \leq 1$.

For sure, we can use the Taylor series but we can do better using the $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$.

This write
$$\tan^{-1}(x)=x\,\frac {1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\,x^{2k} } {1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\,x^{2k} }+k_n \,O(x^{2n+1})$$

I wrote in the table the first coefficients and the error
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{coefficient } a_k& \text{coefficient } b_k & \text{error coefficient}\\
 1 & \left\{\frac{4}{15}\right\} &
   \left\{\frac{3}{5}\right\} & \frac 4 {175}\\
 2 & \left\{\frac{7}{9},\frac{64}{945}\right\} &
   \left\{\frac{10}{9},\frac{5}{21}\right\} & \frac{64}{43659}\\
 3 &
   \left\{\frac{50}{39},\frac{283}{715},\frac{256}{15015}\right\} &
   \left\{\frac{21}{13},\frac{105}{143},\frac{35}{429}\right\}& \frac{256}{2760615} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using those for $x=0.52$ we should obtain
$$\left\{\frac{130663}{272400},\frac{1457959438}{3040456875},
   \frac{315243387069}{657415438750}\right\}$$ which are in an absolute error of $1.54\times 10^{-4}$, $5.62\times 10^{-7}$ and $2.03\times 10^{-9}$.

Another way to look at the accuracy is to consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^1 \left(\tan^{-1}(x)-P_n \right)^2\,dx$$ They are
$3.46\times 10^{-6}$ , $2.06\times 10^{-9}$ and $1.36\times 10^{-12}$

For shortcut calculations in an exam, the first one is sufficient and rewriting it
$$P_1=\frac{x \left(4 x^2+15\right)}{9 x^2+15}$$

**Edit**

In the [linked paper](https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Emignotte/IFT2425/Documents/EfficientApproximationArctgFunction.pdf) kindly provided by @Travis Willse, equation $(11)$
$$\tan^{-1}(x) \simeq \frac x{1+\frac 9{32}x^2}$$ is particularly good and more than simple : maximum error equal to $0.005$ and infinite norm equal to  $7.61\times 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Can I start calling you "Claude the approximating god"?

Comment: @Ajay. You can call me "Claude" that's all ! Take into account that I already spent 63 years building approximations. I love it ! Thanks for the nice words & cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Which approximation is best depends on the value of the argument and the precision you require. For $x \approx 0$, the first- or third-order Taylor polynomial based at $0$ is a good approximation:
$$T_1(x) = x, \qquad T_3(x) = x - \frac{1}{3} x^3.$$
For example, $T_3(0.52) = 0.47951\ldots$ but $\arctan 0.52 = 0.47313\ldots$. Indeed, Taylor's Theorem implies that $T_4(0.52) = T_3(0.52)$ is within $$\frac{24}{5!}(0.52)^5 < 7.761 \cdot 10^{-3}$$ of $\arctan 0.52$.

On the other hand, a consequence of the formula for the linear approximation $T_1$ is that for large $|x|$, $\arctan \frac{1}{x} \approx x$ and so $$\arctan x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \frac{1}{x} \approx \pm\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: There is an exact definition of the constant given in the linked paper.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Which constant do you mean?

Comment: In the linked paper, equation $(11)$. By the way, $0.28125=\frac 9{32}$

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in radians (as you really should...) there is a well known formula.

$\arctan x = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$

This is a formula taught in most calculus classes, but as a precalc student, you are not expected to know this yet.  I should also note that it only converges if $|x|\le 1.$  However, there are tricks and workarounds such that you can work with an x in the appropriate inteval.

However, for $\arctan 0.52,$ since $\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\approx 0.577$, $\arctan 0.52 < \frac {\pi}{3}$ (or $30^\circ$) but only slighty less.